# Recording video and converting it to images through front end web app

Tags: mobile, web-applications, image-uploading, record

So I'm trying to find a JS library that allows me to record video on the mobile device and convert it into images to then upload to the server.

I don't even know if JS is the way to go with this. Essentially I want the front end to do the processing/compressing before the video/images are uploaded to the server.

Any advice on how to do this in a web application? As an extra thing would it be possible to add face tracking?